# Why is $ 1^{\infty} \not= \lim_{t \to \infty} 1^t = 1$?

Tags: limits, infinity

Why is $ 1^{\infty} \not= \lim_{t \to \infty} 1^t = 1$?

It seems like they're saying the same thing. After all, $1$ to the power of any positive integer is equal to $1$.

I suspect that I'm misunderstanding some fundamental concept and would appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.

Thank you.

Comment: $\infty$ is not any positive integer.

Comment: $1^\infty$ is shorthand for "we'd better write out exactly what we mean, which will almost certainly involve a limit."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The '$1$' in $1^\infty$ doesn't represent the *number* one; rather, it's a placeholder for any sequence whose limit is $1$.  In this sense, it's similar to the zeroes in the indeterminate form $\dfrac00$; those aren't *literal* zeroes, but they're stand-ins for an expression whose limit is zero.  The classic example of a $1^\infty$ form, of course, is the exponential limit itself: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n$.  It's true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)=1$, of course, and it's true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=1$; but we can't commute a 'partial' limit and say that if $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}L^{b_n}$.

Comment: Fascinating. What field of mathematics is concerned with this? Real Analysis?

Comment: @ThePointer More or less, but 'concerned' is a very loose word; all of the details of the limits in question tend to get sussed out well before undergraduate studies have been exhausted. I should say that $1^\infty$ isn't really a _formal_ notation so much as it is a sort of mathematical shorthand; it doesn't really show up outside of classes _because_ the concepts involved are so (relatively) elementary that they're just taken as a given by most working mathematicians.

Answer (score 6):

There is an indeterminate form called $1^\infty$.  We say it is indeterminate despite
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} 1^t = 1,
$$
which is correct, but there are other cases like
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x
$$
which have the form $1^\infty$ but do not converge to $1$.